# App Engine app scheduled to be deleted in as soon as 7 days

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

On February 23rd I received an email that they are turning down the App Engine Admin Console and moving to Cloud Platform Console, then on February 25th I received this in email:

> Your Google Cloud Platform project(s): MY_PROJECT_ID [Project Number(s):
>   MY_PROJECT_NUMBER ] has/have been in the billing disabled state for more
>   than 200 days. All related Google Compute Engine resources are
>   **scheduled to be deleted** in as soon as 7 days.
>
> If you take no action within 7 days, you will be unable to recover any
>   resources under Google Compute Engine in this project. If disabling
>   billing was unintentional, please follow the online instructions and
>   re-enable billing for this project within 7 days to avoid the project
>   clean up.

I received this for just one app and I have no idea what is going on. I'm nowhere near exceeding free quota on this app, I get less than 100 visits a month.

By reading their new [billing pages](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) I see that they still have free quota, so why would they delete my app and why just one out of four apps that I have?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not Google. Contact Google Support.

Comment: I just got a very similar email and got confused just as OP did (I have ~5 little free services on GAE for years now). And I was actually looking for the community opinion, not for official google pages/support. I'm extremely happy to be able to quickly find the concise answer below.

Comment: Ditto. I blame it on Google confusing names. I did not even know - nor do i want to know - nor care about - Google Compute Engine. But it sounds *awfully* similar to Google App Engine, which i know and use. So when i received said email, i was startled. Even after finding this q. (thanks!) i was still unsure if killing GCE will affect my GAE ... bad Google, hapless emailer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The email does not say that they are deleting your App Engine app.  They will be deleting Compute Engine resources associated with this app.

You do not need Compute Engine for App Engine.  You may not be using Compute Engine at all and may have started some Compute Engine resources by accident.

Answer (score 3):

...and on the next day they wrote...

> The email quoted below was sent to some Google Cloud Platform
>   customers in error.
>
> If you do not use Google Compute Engine, you can safely ignore that
>   message. We apologize for any confusion this has caused. We received
>   feedback from many customers who do not use the Google Compute Engine
>   service (for example, they only use Google App Engine). Your Google
>   App Engine apps will continue to operate normally, and you do not need
>   to take any action at this time.
>
> Thanks, The Google Compute Engine Team

Comment: I never received this email :/